# OData to Power Query M in C#

Tags: c#, .net, powerquery

I need help on converting the OData to Power Query M expressions. Let's say I have OData Query as

```
ODataQuery: $select=columnA,columnB&$filter=contains(columnC,'Ma')
```

and need to convert to Power Query M Expression like below.

```
let
  Source = OData.Feed("https://localhost/odata"),
  table_name = Source{[Name="table",Signature="table"]}[Data],
  #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(table_name, each (Text.Contains([columnC], "Ma"))),
  #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"columnA", "columnB"})
in
  #"Removed Other Columns"
```

Are there any libraries available for this?

Tried manually, but there are lots of table functions in M language

Comment: Have to ask - why not just add the OData query to the `Source` line?

Comment: Nope, it won't provide any output if the URL contains the OData. If we simply pass
https://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Customers it works and get the output, but if it has Odata like this $count=true&$top=0&$filter=Country%20eq%20%27Germany%27 the output is not coming

Comment: Actually, it worked. Thanks.

It will be more readable when the OData query is huge and I see many follows the same